# I have an Excel file with a table and additional text (comments) on the same sheet. I want to extract ONLY the table. How can I do this in SQL?

Tags: sql, excel, openrowset

So, I am using query `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES; Database={filename};', ['MySheet$']);`.
Problem, that I have few tables on the same sheet with different structures and comments. How to extract such tables into separate queries? Is the only way to import everything and then try to drill down each table using values (like null)?

Comment: I'd try to use `MySheet$` with an address where the table is located, e.g. `MySheet$F20:G25`.